# Android Studio getting deprecated warning even with @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-websettings

In Android Studio, we are getting a deprecated warning during the build. This code is in onCreate(Bundle) of an Activity

```
String databasePath = webView.getContext().getDir("databases", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getPath();
webSettings.setDatabaseEnabled(true);
webSettings.setDatabasePath(databasePath);
```

The method has these annotations

```
@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@TargetApi(19)
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
```

I know setDatabasePath is deprecated, but we need this for backwards compatibility.

I thought that would hide the warning.  When we do the compile task, I see a message like

> .../app/src/main/java/com/.../WebframeActivity.java
>   Warning:(106, 15) [deprecation] setDatabasePath(String) in WebSettings has been deprecated

I thought the @SuppressWarnings annotation would not report this as a warning.  What can I do?  Is this a bug or am I overlooking my mistake?

Comment: I only worry about those sorts of annotations affecting the IDE, not output from a command-line build. Does Android Studio itself, in the code editor, flag your deprecated code in any way?

Comment: If I have the  @SuppressWarnings("deprecation") there Android Studio does not flag it.  If I remove it, Android Studio does correctly show that there is a deprecated method.

Comment: Did you found a solution for this? Seems its still a bug.